# How can I add time in datepicker calendar?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#due_date').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
          yearRange: '-100:+0',
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
 $('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker();
```

REFERENCE

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

use **[jquery datetimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#tp-examples)** it is made with the use of jquery datepicker